# Discord.py Rewrite: Functions suddenly stopped working

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been messing around with the discord bot python rewrite for the last few days. I've noticed that adding multiple functions tends to cause other functions to stop working. I added a looping task that sends a video from a random list of URLs and I initially thought that may be causing the other functions to stop working, but commenting that out still causes issues. It's pretty annoying when you have no error messages to go off of. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import re
from random import randint

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is doing stuff.")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    """Deletes <specific> YT link"""

    if <specific yt link> in message.content: 
        await message.delete()
        print("video deleted")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    "Sends a peeposalute whenever someone says 'goodnight'"

    gn = re.compile('goodnight|good night|gn')
    if gn.search(message.content.lower()): 
        await message.channel.send('<:peepoSalute:665687773407215637>')
        print('peepo has saluted')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    """Checks the #new-uploads channel, reacts to any new messages and adds the video URL to the list"""

    if message.channel.id == <channel id>:
        with open('videos.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(message.content + '\n')
            print("New video added to list")
        message.add_reaction('<:Wowee:592122719546638408>')


@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def daily_video():
    """Sends a random video in #general daily"""

    with open('videos.txt', 'r') as f:
        videos = f.readlines()

    target_general_id = <channel id>
    general_id = client.get_channel(target_general_id)
    await general_id.send(videos[randint(0, len(videos) - 1)])
    print("Daily video sent")

@daily_video.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

daily_video.start()

client.run(<token>)
```

Comment: The simple explanation is you're doing too much work on the thread that asyncio is using; plugging it up. Make sure you don't have any code that's blocking the work thread. Maybe sprinkle some `print`s around or use a debugger to find where it's stopping.

Comment: Or rather, I should have said, "The *likely* explanation is you're doing too much work on the thread that asyncio is using".